# What is an "Architecture Specification" document? (usually from Intel)

Tags: architecture, intel, document, specifications

Hi SW documentation experts,

An "Architecture Specification" template came my way from an ex-Intel employee.

What exactly is the "Architecture Specification" document type?

I have a feeling that this originated at Intel, because when I google "intel.com: "Architecture Specification" " I get over 250,000 hits.

From looking at some of the architecture specifications that Google returned, it seems they are just like any other customer oriented product spec: a customer-oriented document, introducing and explaining a working and finished Intel product and how to program with it.

However the template I received was for an in-house SW design aid (both for high-level design (HLD) and low-level design (LLD)) and not customer-oriented at all.

So I have a feeling that the guy who wrote the template I received got the name wrong.

Are there any old time Intel guys looking in who can verify that the purpose of "architecture specification" documents are indeed customer-oriented documents describing released products (or other wise)?

Thanks,

Avraham

Comment: Do you mean architecture as in ISA for a CPU architecture?  If so, maybe you're talking about Intel's x86 manuals, https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm.  "Architecture Specification"  isn't a term I recognize, but I don't pay close attention to what titles Intel puts on their manuals.

Comment: Hi,
I mean whichever product or system is defined by a document of type "Architecture Specification".  As mentioned, when I google "intel.com: " I get over 250,000 hits of all system types..

Comment: It occurred to me to join an Intel Communities forum and ask there. I hope I will get an answer and report back here, PG.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

"Architecture specification" documents can be anything: customer-oriented or internal, or "high-level" or "low-level".

Note that recently it seems that companies tend not to define what is "high-level" and  "low-level", but define components, blocks etc.

-avraham